# Hard-coding button's width in dimension units

Tags: java, android

I've got the hard-coded layout, consisting of `Button`s, and need to enlarge some of them. I found `Button`'s method `setWidth(int value)`, accepting width in pixels, but I need to set value in `dp`. So, how can I set `dp` value in program code?

Comment: You have not stated what "the problem" is.

Comment: Replaced my own idea with problem-explanaition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TypedValue` lets you do unit conversions - [applyDimension (int unit, float value, DisplayMetrics metrics)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#applyDimension%28int,%20float,%20android.util.DisplayMetrics%29)